# Show discounts on event info page

Tags: cividiscount

Is there a way to display the prices with discounts applied (or a summary table of available discounts) on the event summary page? I found this old issue from 2012 that suggests it used to do this, but I haven't found anything more recent. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-10434

I tried using the api viewer but couldn't wrap my head around the query that would be needed.

[image: The first picture] is the automatically applied discount on the form, [image: the second image] shows what I mean about the info/summary page prior to the form - it lists the price fields but doesn't automatically apply the discounts like it does on the next page. We've simply put a message stating the discount will be applied on the next page, but having it show in the summary helps make it very clear to the user what to expect.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The discounts in core are time-based, so are automatically applied if you are registering before they expire. Do you mean you want to show them how much they are saving by registering early? Can you just put that in the event description?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Demerit - I've updated the original post with screenshots illustrating what I mean.